# How to fix recursive function where the last return every other result in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that appends children to the DOM based on a JSON object, recursively.

The problem I'm running into is that the last `return` in my recursion "overrides" every other result and I'm not really sure why.

This is my code:

```js
var tags = [{
  tag: 'div',
  props: [{
    'class': 'meetup-container'
  }],
  children: [{
    tag: 'div',
    props: [{
      class: 'meetup',
      itemscope: '',
      itemtype: 'http://schema.org/Event'
    }],
    children: [{
      tag: 'p',
      props: [{
        itemprop: 'event'
      }]
    }],
  }]
}, {
  tag: 'a',
  props: [{
    href: '#'
  }]
}]

function buildDom(graph) {
  let element;

  graph.forEach((node) => {
    element = document.createElement(node.tag);

    if (node.props && node.props.constructor === Array) {
      node.props.forEach((prop) => {
        let propNames = Object.keys(prop);
        propNames.forEach((propName) => {
          return element.setAttribute(propName, prop[propName]);
        });
      });
    }

    if (node.children) {
      element.appendChild(buildDom(node.children));
      // return element.appendChild(buildDom(node.children));
    }
  });

  return element;
}

let elements = buildDom(tags);
```

Basically the output that I'm expecting to see is this:

```
<div class="meetup-container">
  <div class="meetup">
      <p itemprop="event"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But what I'm seeing is this:

```
<p itemprop="event"></p>
```

However, if I `console.log` each step of my function, I can see how my function is stepping through the children elements correctly, the problem is that it's not appending them the way they're supposed to go.

Comment: Could there be more children or is there always only one child?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir technically there could be a very large number of children, but for the specific purpose that I'm building, only 5 or 6 levels deep maximum

Comment: The expected output is wrong: some elements are missing some props and the `<a>` element is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code have a few flaws in it:

1. If the array `graph` has more than one element in it, only the last one is returned and not the expected array of elements. To fix that use `map` and return the resulting array.
2. The `return` statement inside `forEach` is useless.
3. The function `buildDom` should return an array of elements as it takes an array of objects (see **1.**), so `element.appendChild(buildDom(node.children));` won't work anymore. Use `forEach` to loop over that array.

With that being said:

```
function buildDom(graph) {
  return graph.map((node) => {
    let element = document.createElement(node.tag);

    if (node.props && Array.isArray(node.props)) {
      node.props.forEach((prop) => {
        let propNames = Object.keys(prop);
        propNames.forEach((propName) =>
          element.setAttribute(propName, prop[propName])
        );
      });
    }

    if (node.children) {
      buildDom(node.children).forEach(child => element.appendChild(child));
    }

    return element;
  });
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function buildDom(graph) {
  return graph.map((node) => {
    let element = document.createElement(node.tag);

    if (node.props && Array.isArray(node.props)) {
      node.props.forEach((prop) => {
        let propNames = Object.keys(prop);
        propNames.forEach((propName) =>
          element.setAttribute(propName, prop[propName])
        );
      });
    }

    if (node.children) {
      buildDom(node.children).forEach(child => element.appendChild(child));
    }

    return element;
  });
}

let tags = [{"tag":"div","props":[{"class":"meetup-container"}],"children":[{"tag":"div","props":[{"class":"meetup","itemscope":"","itemtype":"http://schema.org/Event"}],"children":[{"tag":"p","props":[{"itemprop":"event"}]}]}]},{"tag":"a","props":[{"href":"#"}]}];

let result = document.getElementById("result"),
    elements = buildDom(tags);

elements.forEach(element => result.appendChild(element));
```

```html
Result: (inspect element to see it)
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Good catch! I originally was using `.map` precisely to feed an array back to the function as it takes an array, but probably during my debugging I ended up messing up my function signature. Thanks a lot!